# Quaternion roots for $x^2+2x+2$

Tags: geometry, polynomials, quaternions

So I know there are complex solutions $-1+i$ and $-1-i$ I'm not entirely sure how to describe all quaternion solutions. I know $x^2=-1$ has infinitely many solutions in the quaternions.

I also know you can rotate quaternions, if I take a solution and rotate it around some vector, do those rotations also solve the equation?

Comment: Approximately, if there are no _real_ solutions to a quadratic equation (but complex...), then there are infinitely-many quaternion solutions, and all related by rotations... If you can formulate a somewhat more precise version of your question, it might admit a more precise answer.

Comment: @paul garrett Can any rotation about any quaternion with 0 real coefficient be an axis of rotation? Or will only some quaternions work?

Comment: Reptile, how about if you edit in all solutions to $x^2 + 1 = 0$ in the quaternions...

Comment: @Will Jagy Its all the unit quaternions with real part 0?

Comment: Reptile, you really should find out.

Comment: @Will Jagy I thought is was just a sphere basically, $(b,c,d)$ where $\vert\vert(b,c,d)\vert\vert=1$ and $b,c,d$ are the coefficients on $i,j,k$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep calm and complete the square.  To wit:

$x^2+2x=-2$

$x^2+2x+1=-2+1$

$(x+1)^2=-1$

So $x+1$ is an imaginary unit $u$, described in the usual quaternion notation as $ai+bj+ck$ with $a,b,c$ any real numbers satisfying $a^2+b^2+c^2=1$.  Then, $x=-1+u$.

Comment: Is there a general way of solving polynomials for quaternion solutions? It seems like I gave one of only two examples where this approach works since $x^2+2x+3=0$ if you complete the square you get $(x+1)^2=-2$.